# How can I return all parents of a vertex in arango ql?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I'm trying to write an AQL query that returns all children of a vertex and that vertex itself.

For example I have this structure:

```
  A      B         C
  |      |         |
  D------          E     F
```

This is how my query looks:

```
for parent in collection
for child in outbound parent link
   RETURN{ parent, 
       child
    }
```

But it returns the results in the form

```
"child": D
"parent": A

"child": D
"parent":B

"child": E
"parent": C
```

The result I'm expecting from the query is like

```
"child": D
"parent": A, B

"child": E
"parent": C

"child": F
"parent":
```

How can I amend my query to get the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some messing about, I ended up creating a query suitable for my needs.

```
FOR child in entity
     LET parents = (
            FOR p IN INBOUND child link
            RETURN {parentfp: p.fingerprint, parentTypeFp: p.typeFp})
            RETURN MERGE(\n" +
            {   
              childFp: child.fingerprint,
              childTypeFp: child.typeFp,
              parents
             })
```

Answer (score 0):

`FOR parent IN VertexCollection
    FOR child IN OUTBOUND parent EdgeCollection
    COLLECT c = child.value INTO groups
    RETURN { child: c, parents: groups[*].parent }`

Returns something like this.  But with the document details as well.
`[
  {
    "child": "D",
    "parents": ["A", "B"]
  },
  {
    "child": "E",
    "parents": ["C"]
  }
]`

At first glance this is the approach I would take and returns mostly as you are looking for.  Because `F` has no edge to it you cannot reach it from the second portion of the AQL statement (`FOR child IN OUTBOUND parent EdgeCollection`).  This statement will gather only children.  `F` is technically not a child not parent because it is edgeless.

The COLLECT statement is pretty power and would dig more into that for these type of groupings. https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operations-collect.html

Comment: Thanks, this is really close to what I wanted with the exception that it doesn't return F, (should be child F with empty parents).
However I did manage to come up with something more suitable for my needs.